# Can a bad guy ever get access to my gmail account using ONLY the 2fa app or ONLY the recovery phone (plus username)?

Tags: passwords, multi-factor, google, phone, gmail

- Let's say X is a malicious person.
- Let's say I have a gmail account with a recovery phone and with 2fa
  enabled. Let's say X knows the username but not the password. X doesn't have any other information or factors.
- I'm pretty sure that X can gain access to the account if X obtains BOTH
  access to the recovery phone and the 2fa app (and my username and nothing else).
- **But what if X only has one of those two? Can X *** ***sometimes*** *** gain access
  to the gmail account using just one or the other?** (still assuming they have my username and nothing else)

I ask because I'm wondering whether to put my 2fa on a phone other
than my recovery phone. But of course I realize that if I've allowed
someone to get access to one or both of my phones (and figure out the
PIN and fingerprint and everything), I probably have bigger things to
worry about.

@mentallurg made a good point; as I understand that point, you can definitely ***sometimes*** gain access without both recovery phone and 2fa, because you might have another third thing, such as backup codes.

Comment: @mentallurg I guess maybe I'm confused about 2 things: first, I was thinking that I would still need my password in the process you linked, since the backup code is like a replacement for the 2fa app (that's what I was thinking anyway). Second, I wasn't clear in my question: when I referred to access to the 2fa, I was thinking about access to the app, rather than the backup codes. Maybe the answer is the same either way, but the reason I'm thinking about the app is that this would be easier for me to lose.

Comment: @mentallurg I guess maybe what you're trying to tell me is that technically I can recover my gmail account without either one of those things (phone or 2fa app), if I have a third thing such as the backup codes. If I understand correctly, you're rightt: that means that yes, I can sometimes gain access to the gmail account using just one or the other. I'm going to edit the question because that's not what I was thinking, although it is what I said (oops). I'm going to add that I have no other relevant pieces of information in the scenario I describe.

Comment: @mentallurg Maybe you're also telling me that having the backup codes is pretty much equivalent to having the 2fa app, so if I can recover my account using only backup codes then maybe that means I can recover my account using only the app. I'm still not sure whether I would also need my password in order to do that, I can't tell from those instructions. I tried going through the first part of the account recovery process, and it looks like I can probably recover using only my 2fa app, but I can't tell because I was scared to go past that point.

Comment: (1/2) When I tried that (going through the recovery process), I didn't get straight to "try another way." I had to first either enter my password or click "Forgot Password?" which made me think that the instructions linked above were designed for the scenario where you still know your password. But after I clicked "Forgot Password?" I was able to click the "Try Another Way" link. It didn't want me to use any method other than entering my 2fa code so I think I diverged from the instructions (unless I could have put my backup code in there). But since it asked for 2fa code, that means that I

Comment: (2/2) could have used the backup code to get my authenticator working again, and then used that to sign in. So I think that does still mean that I could get it using only the backup codes and username, and no other info. And that answers my question as originally asked (assuming no steps in the recovery process after entering my 2fa code); I'm sorry for phrasing it wrong. Again I should have added that my scenario involves not having access to anything but the username and (2fa app xor recovery phone); I edited my question to make that clear.

Comment: @mentallurg "backup codes" are not a natural factor to google when the problem statement is expressed this way. The OP has not avoided their due diligence by not thinking of this other factor to consider googling for.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks, I agree it's not obvious and that makes me feel a lot better. :) But it was useful for mentallurg to bring them into the conversation. It forced me to clarify my question and also got me to try going through the account recovery process without providing password. Doing that suggests (doesn't prove) that I can probably recover my google account using only authenticator. If true, that's not really my preferred behavior TBH. (the "2" in 2FA ought to mean something, seems to me!)

Comment: @mentallurg That makes sense as a conclusion, but I think I wasn't clear enough in my post. I think I made it confusing by using the first-person. I'll try to make it clearer. 

What I'm really concerned about is what a malicious actor could do with just my 2fa app, or with just my recovery phone, vs. both. Based on your backup code example, I think (but can't prove) that they could probably get into my account using only the 2fa app by following very similar directions to what you linked. If you think that's right and give it as the answer, I'll mark it as correct (if you think it is).

Comment: I could just test it myself but I'm afraid to go through the recovery process in case that makes my account look suspicious or something, or forces me to not reuse my previous password which I'm happy with for now. Maybe that's stupid, I'm not sure whether any of that would happen. ALSO I edited the post to remove the use of "I" where I'm thinking of a bad guy.

Comment: @carpet As your question demonstrates, it's very difficult to reason about how to best protect your account when 1) the "rules of the game" are unknown, 2) testing to discover the rules runs the risk of destroying something valuable, 3) the rules are variable and keep changing.  Unfortunately, this is the state of the security industry nowadays.  I believe the best way to stay secure is keep a low profile, stay off the beaten path, so you're an uninteresting outlier.  This has the unfortunate side effect of missing out on some of the potential benefits of technology.  That's the trade off.